# Pass parameters from KEY=VALUE properties file to downstream Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my declarative pipeline, I do have the below line to call the downstream job.

```
build job: 'my_downstream_job'
```

I have a file in `KEY=VALUE` format, how to pass in the parameters from this properties file? Downstream job receive this parameter as `KEY`. Using Jenkins GUI, I use "Parameters from properties file" and put this filename in there and it works, like to know how to do the same with pipeline.

Comment: looking for something like: `build job: 'my_downstream_job' parameters: 'file:params.properties'`  where params.properties has `MY_NAME=RODEE`, my_downstream_job receives the parameter as 'MY_NAME' and that works.

Comment: I have this same question. This was supported in the old freestyle jobs, and would be handy in the pipeline world as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might need some extra logic to process this file and construct the appropriate list. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/ for documentation but typically it will look like:

```
build(job: "my_downstream_job",
    parameters: [
        new StringParameterValue('MY_NAME', myname_var),
    ],
    propagate: true
)
```

So you might need to parse your file and create a list if new StringParameterValue's for each line.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that there is a one-liner way to do this, but I got this to work:

```
params = readProperties  file: "params.properties"
build job: 'some_jenkins_job', parameters: [
    string(name: 'PROP_STR', value: params.PROP_STR),
    booleanParam(name: 'PROP_BOOL', value: params.PROP_BOOL),
]
```

And maybe this is for the best, so it's clear exactly which params are being passed in, just by reading the Jenkinsfile.